# Mac users cannot access BigblueButton remote class because Apple has disabled java

Tags: java, macos, bigbluebutton

I am using *BigBluebutton* service in my perl website for remote video classes. But recently we have an issue with our Mac users that cannot access online webclass because Apple has disabled java on newer operating system. *BigblueButton* uses java for some of its functions. Please let me know if we have any alternative solution for this.

http://www.macrumors.com/2013/01/11/apple-blocks-java-7-on-os-x-to-address-widespread-security-threat/

Comment: Yesterday, Oracle released a fix for that vulnerability. It won't take long until it will be unblocked again.

Answer (score 1):

In BigBlueButton 0.80 (release June 19, 2012) we used a self-generated code signing certificate to sign the desktop sharing applet.  Mountain Lion now disables Java applets using self-signed certificates.

In BigBlueButton 0.81 (in development) we have a proper code signing certificate for signing the applet.

To run the BigBlueButton 0.80 applet on Mountain Lion, see this answer  [Java applet with self-signed certificate on OS X Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136805/java-applet-with-self-signed-certificate-on-os-x-mountain-lion)

Regards,... Fred

BigBlueButton Developer